# How to search using SQLAlchemy in a mutable array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use a mutable array to store data with SQLAlchemy and Postgres and have written these classes:

```
class MutableList(Mutable, list):
    def append(self, value):
        list.append(self, value)
        self.changed()

    def pop(self, index=0):
        value = list.pop(self, index)
        self.changed()
        return value

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableList):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                return MutableList(value)
            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value


class Lead(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'leads'

    ...
    starred = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(db.ARRAY(db.Integer)))
```

And I can update the starred property, both appending and popping items from it. The question I have is how to search for row that has a particular item inside the array. Here's my query:

```
leads = Lead.query.order_by(Lead.post_date.desc()).filter(Lead.starred.contains(current_user.id)).all()
```

But that gives me the following error: `ARRAY.contains() not implemented for the base ARRAY type; please use the dialect-specific ARRAY type`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `db.ARRAY` is the SQL standard/multi-vendor array type [`sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY). Instead you should use the dialect specific type (as noted in the error) [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY). In short:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
```

and use that.

Comment: So, should I change my model to: `starred = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(db.Integer)))` instead?

Comment: Given that you've also added the required import, yes.